# I'm having trouble installing USB 3 drivers on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-3

I recently acquired a toshiba laptop which came with Windows 8. I downgraded to Windows 7 and installed the necessary drivers which I obtained here:

http://www.toshiba.co.uk/innovation/windows7_drivers.jsp?service=UK&selCategory=2&selFamily=2&selSeries=365&selProduct=7973&selShortMod=null&language=13&selOS=30&selType=all&yearupload=&monthupload=&dayupload=&useDate=null&mode=allMachines&search=&action=search&macId=&country=4&page=1

However, the USB 3 ports don't work though my single USB 2 port does.

I have tried to use windows update to suggest a fix but this also has little results.

When I go to the device manager and "update driver software..." I get no where either.

I know I have an administrator account.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in `device manager`? Do the ports show? Do they show as needing a driver?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download USB 3 drivers for your toshiba laptop for windows 7. As USB 3 ports only work after installing these drivers and will not work installing only USB 2 ports. If you used that link to download I don't think they gave you any USB 3 driver. You can download these from:
1.http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/download/23692,usb-3-0-driver.html
2.http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp

or you can also Google for that driver listing your laptop model.